# How can I delete a row using mysql and python using variable names?

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to figure out a way to use variable names previously defined to delete a row from a table

Ive tried using this:
`formula = ("DELETE FROM vault.logins WHERE loginuser = 'adddbuser' AND webuser = 'userentry' AND webpass = 'passentry' AND  website = 'webentry'")` - but it results in nothing happening, but no error message pops up

```
def confirmexists():

newuserentry1 = newuserentry.get()
newpassentry1 = newpassentry.get()
newwebentry1 = newwebentry.get()

global userentry1
global passentry1
global webentry1

userentry1 = userentry.get()
passentry1 =  passentry.get()
webentry1 = webentry.get()

formula = ("DELETE FROM vault.logins WHERE loginuser = 'adddbuser'") # not working

formula1 = ("INSERT INTO logins (loginuser, webuser, webpass, website) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
editing = (adddbuser, newuserentry1, newpassentry1, newwebentry1)

print("Success")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(formula)
mydb.commit()
mycursor.execute(formula1, editing)
mydb.commit()
print("Successfully edited 1 user/pass combo")
successadd()
```

The code is for a project, and is used for a password storing database, adding to the database works but when using this edit function, it doesnt delete the one being edited and instead only adds the new one.

loginuser, webuser, webpass and website being the columns, I cant seem to figure out a way to delete them

userentry, webentry, passentry are all storing the details that the user WANTS to be edited, and then newuserentry, newpassentry, and newwebentry are the details that the user wants to change them to.

adddbuser is the storing of the username of the account that is changing the passwords, so it only changes the information only related to that account.

userentry, passentry, webentry, newuserentry, newpassentry, and newwebentry are all StringVar(), and if thats the problem then im not sure on how to fix it, as then you arent able to use .get().

Im not too knowledgeable so Id like if someone could help me out

Comment: This should work, assuming you're correctly executing it as an SQL query.  Of course it won't do anything if you just define it as a string variable.

Comment: In any case, we can't help more without seeing an actual complete code example.

Comment: what does `SELECT count(*) FROM vault.logins WHERE loginuser = 'adddbuser' AND webuser = 'userentry' AND webpass = 'passentry' AND  website = 'webentry'` do?

Comment: Ive just updated it to include some more information, but with what John said, I'm not too sure how to get the code to work if its not defined as a string varaible and why that affects it

Comment: Is `adddbuser` the actual username, or is it supposed to be a python variable that contains the actual username?

Comment: It is a python variable that contains the actual username that the user enters:

adddbuser = usernameentry.get()

where usernameentry is the name of the entry box that the user types into